# SQL-Getting Character length issue in a column, but can't reproduce using a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a column in a table with length nvarchar(60), but when I try to update the column with string 'THE # 1 INTERNATIONAL BESTSELLER' of 32 characters it is throwing an error

*Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
String or binary data would be truncated in table 'dbo.table', column 'x'. Truncated value: 'THE # 1 INTERNATIONAL BESTSELL'.*

But, when I try reproducing the error with a variable like below, it works.

```
declare @x nvarchar(60)
select @x='THE # 1 INTERNATIONAL BESTSELLER'
print @x
```

Can anybody please help me understand this.

Comment: Perhaps you have hidden characters in the string that is being assigned.  Another possibility is that the table has an `update` trigger that is generating the error.

Comment: seems like the column is defined as varchar(60). Post the table definition.

Comment: Show the actual code used, not your "simulation" that does not involve an actual table.

Answer (score 0):

can u try like this ?

```
declare @x nvarchar(60)
select @x=REPLACE(REPLACE('THE # 1 INTERNATIONAL BESTSELLER',char(10),''),char(13),'')
print @x
```